# How do you get stargazer to recognise a model from lmList?

Tags: r, lm, lme4, stargazer

I have data for three different years and are running a regression for each seperate year with lmList(). When I try to get the LaTex code with stargazer, I get an error saying it doesn't recognize the object type. When running stargazer for a normal linear regression, it works just fine, even though the class for the objects are the same.

This is my regression with lmList

```
fit <- lmList((lndeltaoms) ~ size + factor(gender)| year, data = tser)
stargazer(fit[["2008"]])
% Error: Unrecognized object type.
```

Compare this to a normal regression, where it works.

```
fit2 <- lm((lndeltaoms) ~ size + factor(gender), data=tser)
stargazer(fit2)
```

But when i compare the classes, they're the same.

```
class(fit[["2008"]])
[1] "lm"
```

```
class(fit2)
[1] "lm"
```

Since they're the same class, it feels stargazer should recognize both of them in the same way, but there seems to be some issue when extracting a  model from the lmList.

Is there any way I can work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work fine with `lmList()` from the `nlme` package (not the one from the  `lme4`). Try out:

```
fit1 <- nlme::lmList((lndeltaoms) ~ size + factor(gender)| year, data = tser)
stargazer(fit1[["2008"]]) # ok

fit2 <- lme4::lmList((lndeltaoms) ~ size + factor(gender)| year, data = tser)
stargazer(fit2[["2008"]]) # this does not work
```

It looks like `stargazer()` works fine with objects of class `lmList` but not with `lmList4` object resulting from `lme4::lmList()`.

Also, be careful while loading `nlme` since its function `lmList()` is masked from `lme4::lmList()`.